# Is SetTimer deprecated?

Tags: timer, compact-framework

First of all I'm using the Windows Embedded Compact 2013 Framework...

MSDN says that [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502602.aspx) is deprecated but they don't suggest what to use instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You Can start a thread with some sleep inside or usw thread.timer